# Looping a series of variables in R while doing a cbind()

Tags: r

I have already read a dataset in R though `read.csv` and after doing some calculations created the following 10 variables of similar names, PI_1,PI_2,.....,PI_10

Now I combine the newly formed variables with my existing dataset (TempData).

```
x<-cbind(TempData,PI_1,PI_2,PI_3,PI_4,PI_5,PI_6,PI_7,PI_8,PI_9,PI_10)
```

Is there any smarter way of doing this (maybe by a loop). Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You should have created a single list with ten elements in the first place, then you can just loop over the elements...

Comment: @Sayantandasadhikari  Could you confirm whether it worked or not?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the files are in the working directory and all of them starts with `PI_` followed by some digits `\\d+`, we can use `list.files` with `pattern` argument in case there are other files also in the directory.  To check the working directory, use `getwd()`

```
  files <- list.files(pattern='^PI_\\d+')
```

This will give the file names.  Now, we can use `lapply` and read those files in the `list` using `read.table`.  Once, we are done with that part, use `do.call(cbind` to bind all the dataset columns together.

```
  res <- do.call(cbind,lapply(files, function(x) 
                     read.table(x, header=TRUE)))
```

#### Update

I guess you need to create `10` variables based on some `PI`.  In the code that was provided in the comments, `PI` seems to be an object with some value inside it.  Here, I am creating `PI` as the value as it is not clear.  I created a dummy dataset.

```
  TempData[paste0('PI_', 1:10)] <- Map(function(x,y) c('', 'PI')[(x==y)+1],
                                  1:10, list(TempData$Concept)) 

   head(TempData,3)
  #  Concept        Val PI_1 PI_2 PI_3 PI_4 PI_5 PI_6 PI_7 PI_8 PI_9 PI_10
  #1      10 -0.4304691                                                 PI
  #2      10 -0.2572694                                                 PI
  #3       3 -1.7631631             PI
```

You could use `write.table` to save the results

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(Concept=sample(1:10,50, replace=TRUE), Val=rnorm(50))
write.csv(dat, 'Concept.csv', row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
TempData <- read.csv('Concept.csv')
str(TempData)
#'data.frame':  50 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Concept: int  10 10 3 9 7 6 8 2 7 8 ...
# $ Val    : num  -0.43 -0.257 -1.763 0.46 -0.64 ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not able to write the variables in a new datafile. I am sharing the entire program so that you can guess myntention.                          TempData<-read.csv("Concept.csv") attach(TempData) for(i in 1:10){assign(paste("PI_", i, sep = ""),ifelse(Concept==i,PI,""))}
x<-cbind(TempData,PI_1,PI_2,PI_3,PI_4,PI_5,PI_6,PI_7,PI_8,PI_9,PI_10)write.table(x,sep="\t",file="Final.txt",row.names=F)